# css Z-Index not working on mobile and smaller screen

Tags: css, mobile, css-selectors, z-index

I have a couple of items with stuff in it. I can go through it using a dot navigation system.
I want the dots to be shown in all items, except the first one. I did this with the following code:

```
    .Quiz-carousel .carousel_item:nth-child(1) .owl-dots{
        z-index: -2 ;
    }
```

This works perfectly on my laptop screen, but whenever I make my screen smaller and reload the dots do not appear and when I try it on mobile the dots are everywhere (also on the first page). Does anybody know how I can make it work on all devices?

btw It's z-index -2 cause the items are already -1

Comment: Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide us with a functional example of your code that we can troubleshoot? It may be as simple as adding a `@media` query https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp or you could have a layout issue that's pushing the dots around. Either way it's hard to tell without seeing what you're working on :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, my guess would be that it's something to do with either the positioning of the content or the content doesn't have a height. If you're displaying the dots in CSS, they need a width AND a height for them to show up, since a tag that doesn't have content will just have a height of 0.